# 500 internal server error in an ASP.NET MVC 3 web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpwebrequest

I have a web application in ASP MVC 3. In development environment, everything works fine, in a production environment there is a page which throws a 500 error but not every time. For example when open this page for the first time it works, but when I do it 3 times it throws this 500 error.

I thought that maybe it could be a timeout issue, so I added this code in the web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

but it didn't solve the problem.

Any suggestions ?

EDIT

This is the action that calls the partial view :

```
public ActionResult _PopupDiscussion(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.id = id == null ? null : id;
        return PartialView("PartialViews/_PopupDiscussion");
    }
```

then inside the partial view there is an AJAX request which calls this action:

```
public ViewResult PopupDiscussion_Content(DiscussionModelView model, int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.id = id;
        // some code here
        return View(model);
    }
```

I tried to turn off custom errors like this :

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: We the community find it quiet hard to guess all of your code with just one error message.

Comment: Paste in some at least some code to expect an answer.

Comment: Change your web.config to turn off custom errors too and post the actual error you receive.

Comment: Are you checking that on Internet Explorer? If so, you'll need to uncheck the "Show friendly messages" option on the IE Preferences

Comment: Actually it's an Ajax query so I can see the error only in firebug console

Comment: I always setup Log4net so I can get a better view of what the errors are. You may want to look into doing that and save a bit of headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by calling an action inside the controller from a partial view.
I modified this by using `@Html.Partial()` instead of `@Html.Action()` and everything works just fine